# Problema al hacer un desplegable de 3 columnas en bootstrap, no me despliega todo desde la tercera columna

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

espero puedan ayudarme con este inconveniente que tengo:

Quiero hacer con Boostrap lo siguiente, una fila de 3 columnas, en la primera va un título, en la segunda una mini descripción y en la tercera un botón de flecha hacia abajo que indique que se puede expandir y contraer todo el grupo de columnas, dejo el ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo de lo que deseo]

Sin embargo, al momento armar el código, no me destá desplegando de la forma que quiero,dejo el ejemplo del código hasta donde lo llevo:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Accordion in Column Layout</title>
    <!-- Enlaza los archivos CSS de Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Enlaza los archivos JavaScript de Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Columna 1 -->
            <div class="col border-end">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample1">
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne1">
                            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="collapseOne1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne1" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample1">
                            <div class="accordion-body">
                                Contenido de la primera columna del acordeón.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Columna 2 -->
            <div class="col border-end">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample2">
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo2">
                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
                                Collapsible Group Item #2
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="collapseTwo2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample2">
                            <div class="accordion-body">
                                Contenido de la segunda columna del acordeón.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Columna 3 con botón para expandir/colapsar todo el acordeón -->
            <div class="col">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample3">
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree3">
                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree3" onclick="toggleAll()">
                                Expandir / Colapsar Todo
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function toggleAll() {
            var collapses = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse');
            collapses.forEach(function(collapse) {
                var isShown = collapse.classList.contains('show');
                if (isShown) {
                    collapse.classList.remove('show');
                } else {
                    collapse.classList.add('show');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Alguien podría indicarme cómo hacer que la tercera columna obligue a las otras a desplegarse de la manera correcta? He intentado varias veces y nada aún, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes aprovechar la clase `collapse` sin necesidad de usar un `accordion`.

Te planteo esta propuesta que se ve un poco laboriosa, pero que puedes mejorar una vez comprendido el concepto.

Presta mucha atención al contenido oculto en cada fila ya que cambia el `id` así `id="collapse2"` para poder identificar el contenido que se debe mostrar u ocultar al hacer click en el botón correspondiente `data-bs-target="#collapse2"`

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Accordion in Column Layout</title>
    <!-- Enlaza los archivos CSS de Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Enlaza los archivos JavaScript de Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Fila 1 - Columna 1 -->
            <div class="col border-end">
                <div class="">
                    Título primera fila.
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fila 1 - Columna 2 -->
            <div class="col border-end">
                <div class="">
                    Contenido primera fila.
                </div>
                <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        Contenido oculto de la primera fila. Esta información está oculta por defecto pero se muestra al hacer click en el botón o se oculta al hacer click nuevamente.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fila 1 - Columna 3 con botón para expandir/colapsar el contenido -->
            <div class="col">
                <div class="first-button">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        Expandir / Colapsar Fila 1
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <!-- Fila 2 - Columna 1 -->
            <div class="col border-end">
                <div class="">
                    Título segunda fila.
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fila 2 - Columna 2 -->
            <div class="col border-end">
                <div class="">
                    Contenido segunda fila.
                </div>
                <div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        Contenido oculto de la segunda fila. Esta información está oculta por defecto pero se muestra al hacer click en el botón o se oculta al hacer click nuevamente.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fila 2 - Columna 3 con botón para expandir/colapsar el contenido -->
            <div class="col">
                <div class="second-button">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        Expandir / Colapsar fila 2
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oye muchas gracias por tu respuesta, se agradece mucho, no la había visto, la voy a aplicar.

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta y darle al upvote si te ayuda a resolver tu inquietud, así ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad y ayudamos a futuros visitantes que tengan la misma duda o una similar. O en caso contrario, si faltan detalles, deja un comentario.